# Preposition following "um" in an "um ... zu" construction

Tags: conjunction, infinitive

I've been wanting to translate a sentence:

> He needs more time to reply to your letter.

Here's what I've written:

> Er braucht mehr Zeit, um auf Ihren Brief zu antworten.

I wanted to inquire if it's okay to use another preposition after **um**.

Comment: A possibility would be "Er braucht mehr Zeit, [um] Ihren Brief zu **be**antworten.". The "um" is optional in this case.

Comment: Thanks, but why would it be optional? Doesn't the sentence imply the 'in order to' construction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because this **um** is not a preposition. It's a subordinating sentence conjunction. There are various morphs in German that can be either, and it's not a problem to combine them like this if the syntax allows it.

You can even combine two instances of the *same* morph when it fuilfills different roles, like this:

> Ich brauche zwei Stunden, um um den See zu laufen

This might be slightly dispreferred for reasons of euphony, but syntactically it's perfectly okay.

Comment: But it’s not a sentence conjunction either. *um den See zu laufen* is not a sentence, neither is *um um den see zu laufen.*

Comment: The structure is an "Infinitiv mit zu" (infinitive clause with "zu"), which is fairly common in German. And yes, it does no have to be "auf" after "um".